# AFrame: how to add a touch event listener to an entity

Tags: touch, aframe

In mobile browser, I want to do something when user touches an image, but I don't know how to use touch listeners. Is there some components that I can use? Or give me some idea how to do it on my own.

Comment: Refer this link,

http://jsfiddle.net/lisatinglu/zvoj2zsb/

Answer (score 3):

A-Frame supports DOM events very similarly to web normal pages. Example:

```
<a-scene>
  <!-- Target -->
  <a-box id="target" material="color: green"></a-box>

  <!-- Camera + Cursor -->
  <a-entity camera>
    <a-entity cursor="fuse: true; fuseTimeout: 500"
            position="0 0 -1"
            geometry="primitive: ring; radiusInner: 0.02; radiusOuter: 0.03"
            material="color: black; shader: flat">
    </a-entity>
  </a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

And then in JavaScript:

```
var targetEl = document.querySelector('#target');
targetEl.addEventListener('click', function() {
  targetEl.setAttribute('material', {color: 'red'});
});
```

See A-Frame's [cursor component documentation](https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/components/cursor.html) for more details.

Comment: There may be a problem with my expression.What I want to do is click the target box directly on the mobile screen by hand and then trigger a click event instead of using the cursor or mouse.I have tried use dom event，but nothing happend.

Comment: Tanks for your help, use the mouse-cursor compnent can do it ,if someone encounter the same problem,refer this link [mouse-cursor](https://github.com/mayognaise/aframe-mouse-cursor-component)

Answer (score 0):

I was just searching for the same thing. I found another solution, aframe-mouse-cursor-component.

https://github.com/mayognaise/aframe-mouse-cursor-component