# Aframe click button with eventlistener

Tags: javascript, button, event-listener, aframe, virtual-reality

I try to execute an action when user press a button (An event listener needed because https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/), but I guess, I have some syntax/logic mistake. Some help would be nice :D.

Here is the code:

**HTML:**

```
   <a-image id="playbutton_1" position="-5 0 0" width="2" height="2" rotation="0 -90 0" ></a-image>
```

**JS:**

```
var playthisvid_1 = document.querySelector('#playbutton_1');

    playthisvid_1.addEventListener('click', () => { console.log("it clicks");  })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aframe elements won't simply react to touch / mouse events. You need a `ray` based cursor.

A good way to simulate the mouse is with the `cursor`s attribute:

```
<a-scene cursor="rayOrigin: mouse">
```

It should also work with touch events on mobile devices.

Check it out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/njL1uofh/1/).

---

Otherwise use the a-frame cursor.

```
<a-cursor></a-cursor>
```

Comment: i get this Unhandled Promise Rejection: NotAllowedError: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.
on iphone if i try to play a video with the listener any idea why it appears?

Comment: is it on safari, or other browsers ? If not, can you check if it works on other browsers on iOS ?

Comment: dosn´t work on chrome/safari on iphone (desktop everthings fine)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51878346/aframe-video-only-plays-muted-on-ios here some more informations

Comment: thx now it works. The problem was the button in your examplepage isn´t in the a-scene its a normal html-element. So i changed my <a-image> to an normal <image> and it works. Only problem i can´t gaze on them now with my cardboard.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with aframe. The javascript code is working perfect. I just replaced the aframe element with a normal button and the function is working.

```js
var playthisvid_1 = document.querySelector('#playbutton_1');

    playthisvid_1.addEventListener('click', () => { console.log("it clicks");  })
```

```html
<a id="playbutton_1" href="#">Test</a>
```

Maybe this can solve your problem ?
[AFrame: how to add a touch event listener to an entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43154929/aframe-how-to-add-a-touch-event-listener-to-an-entity)

Comment: thx for the information looks like i need a workaround for aframe :)

Comment: Yes :) no problem

Answer (score 0):

check this out for a complete example:

https://curious-electric.com/w/experiments/aframe/audiosprite/

It is an audio example, but the same technique applies for video (i.e. get the user to click a button first).

Best, Dirk

Comment: thx i tried to use it but it still won´t work with <a-image> the console says the value of my button is always zero.

Comment: var vrButton = document.querySelector('#playbutton_1');

  var enter = function () {
    console.log("it clicks");
  }

  vrButton.addEventListener('click', enter);

Comment: Could you post your full example in a codepen or jsFiddle?